# How to solve invalid authenticity token error in Rails when sending form data from external page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a WordPress page that I built before I learned Rails. On the page there is a form. I want to send the form data to a Rails route. But i get an invalid authenticity token error. How do I satisfy rails with an authenticity token since I understand that they are created by the Rails app itself and therefore would never exist outside of Rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this sounds like a separate app that you want to use to post data to a rails endpoint, you probably don't care about CSRF issues for the controller action that handles this. You could disable the authenticity token verification for your controller action with:

```
# inside your controller class
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, only: [:your_wordpress_action]
```